# How to get all xpaths from an xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How can you get a list of all xpaths from an xml document?

```
<Tee Surname="Ray" Age="24">
<Login id="51" mid="1" "/>
<Server id="1" mid="144"/>
</Tee>
```

for example i want to get a list of all xpaths from the above xml

Comment: You'll have to define more precisely exactly what you mean by "all xpaths".  Show us a few examples of XML documents along with the output you need, and also the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

XPath is a search expression. You cannot "get all XPaths" from an XML document. This is like asking for all possible SQL statements from a database.

Comment: ok , i am sorry for using the word xpath, i just ran out of a proper description of what i want. Given the above xml , i want a list of the following: Tee.@Surname=Ray,Tee.@Age=24, Tee.Login.@id=51, Tee.Login.@mid=1, Tee.Server.@id=1,Tee.Server.@mid=144